# Question left open: How do I store my vinyl records?

Tags: discussion

[Should I store my vinyl records side by side or in piles?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/249/7708)

This looks more like a Music SE question than a Music Fans SE question.  I flagged/voted for closure but it is left open when the review was completed.

Can this question please be closed?

Comment: This would most likely not be received well on music se as it's not really the point of the site to talk about how you store your archive of music. Music fans makes much more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some topics may be on-topic on more than one site, but that does not mean a question has to be marked as off-topic if it is asked in a sub-optimal site.

In this particular case, I actually think that Music Fans SE is the more optimal site for the question under discussion. As such, I had voted to "Leave Open" when it appeared in the review queue.

I also just noticed that the question was in the Close Votes Review Queue *again*. I'd advise not repeatedly flagging/voting for closure if the review has been completed. If your flag/vote is aged away, then it makes sense to repeat it, but this way you're only increasing the number of tasks the community members have to perform for no good reason.

---

I'd like to add that our Help section on what is [on-topic](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) does not explicitly mention that some questions can be a good fit on more than one site. This is possibly because the only other site where a question is likely to be on-topic is Music SE. But, contrast this with the corresponding help section on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)—it has a detailed subsection titled **What might be better asked elsewhere**. Perhaps we can add similar details to our help section as well, should the need arise.

Answer (score 2):

This question would fit on either of the two sites, but it's probably a better fit here. You flagged it for closure and you were outvoted. There is very little sense in immediately re-flagging it as you have done. The result will almost certainly be the same.